# How exactly does the 'reference' typedef behave?

Tags: c++, stl, reference, typedef

STL containers have a `reference` and `const_reference` `typedef`, which, in many cases I've seen (containers of `bool` being the only exceptions I can think of), could be trivially defined as

```
typedef value_type& reference;
typedef const value_type& const_reference;
```

What exactly, however, are the *semantics* of these types?

From what I understand, they are supposed to "behave like references to the value type", but what exactly does that mean?

MSDN says that `reference` is:

> A type that provides a reference to an element stored in a vector.

But what does this mean, exactly? Do they need to overload specific operators, or have a specific behavior? If so, what is the required behavior?

Comment: I don't think anybody is understanding this question. He's asking what the type that is called a "reference" needs to behave like. Not the C++ reference type (like `int&`).

Comment: On second thoughts, I don't think I understand the Q at all now.The type `reference` or `const_reference` behaves like an normal reference or const reference behaves,Why do you think it should behave any differently?

Comment: @Als: The question, quite literally, is: What does "behaves like an normal reference" mean? It's a vague sentence by itself, so I don't know what conditions I would need to satisfy before my type "behaves like a normal reference" (if I were making a container, for example).

Comment: That would essentially reduce your real question to *What is a Reference? What operations should it support & What are operations that an Reference exposed through my interface support?* It is not really related to Standard Library containers at all.

Answer (score 4):

I think part of the question comes from an assumption that allocators are useful.  Allocators (at least pre-C++11) [were something of a late addition to the STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/drdobbs-interview.html):

> People wanted containers independent of the memory model, which was somewhat excessive because the language doesn't include memory models. People wanted the library to provide some mechanism for abstracting memory models. Earlier versions of STL assumed that the size of the container is expressible as an integer of type `size_t` and that the distance between two iterators is of type `ptrdiff_t`. And now we were told, why don't you abstract from that? It's a tall order because the language does not abstract from that; C and C++ arrays are not parameterized by these types. We invented a mechanism called "allocator," which encapsulates information about the memory model. That caused grave consequences for every component in the library. You might wonder what memory models have to do with algorithms or the container interfaces. If you cannot use things like `size_t`, you also cannot use things like `T*` because of different pointer types (`T*`, `T huge *`, etc.). Then you cannot use references because with different memory models you have different reference types. There were tremendous ramifications on the library.

Unfortunately, [they turned out to be substandard](http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html):

> I invented allocators to deal with Intel's memory architecture. They are not such a bad ideas in theory - having a layer that encapsulates all memory stuff: pointers, references, `ptrdiff_t`, `size_t`. Unfortunately they cannot work in practice. For example,

```
vector<int, alloc1> a(...);
vector<int, alloc2> b(...);
```

> you cannot now say:

```
find(a.begin(), a.end(), b[1]);
```

> `b[1]` returns a `alloc2::reference` and not `int&`. It could be a type mismatch. It is necessary to change the way that the core language deals with references to make allocators really useful.

The `reference` typedef is meant to return whatever the equivalent of `T&` is for the allocator in question.  On modern architectures, this is probably `T&`.  However, the assumption was that on some architectures it could be something different (e.g., a compiler targeting an architecture with "near" and "far" pointers might need special syntax for "near" and "far" references).  Sadly, this brilliant idea turned out to be less-than-brilliant.  C++11 makes substantial changes to allocators -- adding scoped allocators -- and the memory model.  I have to admit I don't know enough about C++11's changes w.r.t. allocators to say if things get better or worse.

---

Looking at the comments on the original question, since the Standard does not actually state how the containers must be implemented (although the Standard does put so many requirements on the behavior of the containers that it might as well ...), whatever type you typedef as `reference` must have the behaviors of `T&` that somebody could potentially rely on when implementing the container:  an object of type `reference` should be a transparent alias to the original object, assigning to it should change the value of the original object without slicing, there is no need to support "reseating" the `reference`, taking the address of the `reference` should return the address of the original object, etc.  If at all possible, it should in fact be `T&`; and the only case I can imagine where it wouldn't be possible would be if you were allocating memory that you couldn't manipulate through pointers or references (e.g., if the "memory" were actually on disk, or if the memory were actually allocated on a separate computer and reachable over the network through RPC calls, etc.).

Comment: This seems to be for STL, not STD.

Comment: "the only case I can imagine where it wouldn't be possible would be if you were allocating memory that you couldn't manipulate through pointers or references" The standard wouldn't let you create allocators with that anyway, because you cannot fake a reference in C++. You cannot give an object reference sematics. That's why `vector<bool>` is not technically a standard container. It does not follow the rules laid down for `std::vector` instantiations. And it does not because you have to be able to do `&vec[3]`, which is impossible with `vector<bool>`.

Comment: @Pubby:  the STL existed before the standard, and was significantly changed when it became part of the standard (one change being that 2/3 of the algorithms Stepanov originally had were removed).  According to Stepanov, C++ was changed in some ways when the STL was adopted into the standard (one change being the addition of functors).  My comments in the final paragraph of the answer are, I believe, only "correct" for C++-98.  C++-03 changed the rules such that implementations are allowed to assume `reference` is, in fact, `T&` (as your answer states, quite clearly).

Answer (score 2):

Taken out of the standard:

[image]

It also defines `reference` as a typedef of `value_type&` which is a typedef of `T`

(New answer as previous one was different focus)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is "Can I always dereference a reference? And yes, you can. That means dereferenced `reference` can do everything dereferenced `value_type&` can do which is everything `value_type` can do. If that makes sense to you.

---

You can't overload operators on typedefs. typedefs have the same behavior as the type they are assigned to. The reason they are typedef'd is to make them less cumbersome and provide a common "interface"

The reason `reference` exists is to prevent things like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  T& bar();

  typedef T& reference;
  reference baz();
}

foo<int> x;
foo<int>::T& y = x.bar(); // error! returns a T& but I can't create one!
foo<int>::reference z = x.baz(); // ok!
```

It also makes a cleaner interface and allows use of SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
typename T::reference second(T::reference& t) { return t.at(1); };

template<typename T>
T& second(T& t) { return t[1]; };

std::vector v(10);
foo f(10); // type with [] overloaded but no reference typedef
second(x) = 5; // calls first def
second(f) = 3; // calls second def
```

Comment: Sorry but I think you missed the question. I was asking what operators/features the `reference` type must support... not whether or not I can overload what's there... I already know how `typedef` works and why they introduced the abstraction, etc.; I'd just like to know what a `reference` must satisfy according to the standard.

Comment: @Mehrdad `reference` can do everything `value_type&` can do which is  everything `value_type` can do.

Comment: Then what's the point of using `reference` when you can just use `value_type&`, if they're the same thing? There *has* to be a set of necessary and sufficient conditions that `reference`s must satisfy, which is certainly *not* "everything"...

Comment: @Mehrdad It adds descriptiveness. What if I accidentally wrote `value_type` when I meant to write `value_type&`? Bugs like that are very hard to find, but are completely avoidable if I were to use `reference`.

Comment: "There has to be a set of necessary and sufficient conditions that references must satisfy, which is certainly not "everything"..." Why? The original intent of `reference` was to be something that _could_ be a "convertible-to" type. But standard containers don't allow that. Therefore, `reference` must be nothing more and nothing less than `value_type&`. Not everything that exists in C++ has to have a reason. Sometimes, it's just something that worked out a certain way.

Comment: @Mehrdad It may be worth noting that `T::value_t &varname;` is syntactically ambiguous: the compiler doesn't know if `value_t` is a variable (and you're taking the bitwise-and) or a type (and you're declaring a variable). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typename#A_method_for_indicating_that_a_dependent_name_is_a_type